# Python Pandas groupby-apply strange behavior

Tags: pandas

Can anyone help me understand why there is different behavior between the two calls to apply below?  Thank you.

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  1  7  4
2  2  9  8
3  2  2  4
4  2  2  1
5  3  3  3
6  3  3  2
7  3  5  7

In [35]: g = df.groupby('A')

In [36]: g.apply(max)
Out[36]: 
   A  B  C
A         
1  1  7  4
2  2  9  8
3  3  5  7

In [37]: g.apply(lambda x: max(x))
Out[37]: 
A
1    C
2    C
3    C
dtype: object
```

Comment: Check out the difference between `max(df)` and `df.max()`. I think this is the same behavior.

Comment: @PaulH This should have been an answer.

Comment: @AmiTavory ehh. chrisb did I better job explaining it than I would have.

Comment: @PaulH IINM, I wrote this comment before his (fine!) answer

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - you probably just want

```
df.groupby('A').max()
```

Longer answer - `max` is a generic python function that finds the max of any iterable.  Because iterating a `DataFrame` is over the columns, calling the python max just finds the "largest" column, which happens in your second case.

In the first case - `pandas` has intercept logic, which turns things like `g.apply(sum)` into `g.sum()`.

Comment: Congratulations on 10k!